# Can the Licensing Manager API retrieve Drive quota usage?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-license-manager

The Google Licensing Manager API, https://developers.google.com/google-apps/licensing/, can be used to assign Drive licenses to users in an Apps domain. How can you retrieve the amount of storage a given user is actually using and not just what their total quota is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can't be done in the Licensing Manager API, it only retrieves information about the actual storage licences. The amount of quota a user has actually used can be found with about call in the Drive API, documented at https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/about/get. Specifically the `quotaBytesUsed` property.